# Толкин или Толкиен?

Tags: заимствования, ономастика

Пишут и так, и так в зависимости от переводчика. Мне как-то больше нравится через Е — Толкиен. А как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если учитывать произношение фамилии, то правильно *Толкин*. Встречается также транслитерационный (учитывающий написание, а не произношение) вариант *То́лкиен*. В письме к Ричарду Джеффери от 17 декабря 1972 года Толкин отмечал: «Мою фамилию постоянно пишут (кроме тебя) как Tolkein. Не знаю, в чём причина, поскольку всегда произношу окончание как -кин» («I am nearly always written to as Tolkein (not by you): I do not know why, since it is pronounced by me always -keen». «The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien», № 347